# Cancan's 'load_and_authorize_resource' calls Model.new causing unexpected failures in RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

Using RSpec and Cancan, I have this test which fails with:

```
Failure/Error: User.should_receive(:new).and_return(@user)
expected: 1 time
received: 2 times
```

because
load_and_authorize_resource seems to call 'new' on the object as well. How do I work around this?

```
it "creates a new staff member" do
  User.should_receive(:new).and_return(@user)
  get :new, :format => "js"
end
```

-

```
 class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

    load_and_authorize_resource

    def new
      @user = User.new()
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

- either replace `load_and_authorize_resource` with `authorize_resource`

Or:

- remove `@user = User.new()` (which bears unnecessary parentheses)

You're definitely doing things twice here.